# Node js returning specific time to setInterval after break

Tags: node.js

I'm studying Nodejs and trying to run this script what loops a function.
How to send the time variable to setInterval everytime after the break?
In this example The first interval is 15000ms then, when the script continue running, will be changed according whether variable was met.
After first and second "ifs", time needs to be 14000ms, then the script will loop again then meet the third and forth "ifs", changing the time to 15000ms again.
Not sure if I was clear but here is the code.

```
let app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hi');
});
var time = 15000;
function grebData(time)
{

    try{
        if (something1){
            var i=0;
            while(true){
                i++;
                if(i===1){

                    if (something2){
                        time = 14000;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                       }
                                       
                setTimeout(grebData,time);
            }
        if (something3){
            var i=0;
            while(true){
                i++;
                if(i===1){
    
                    if (something4){
                        time = 15000;
                        }
                    break;
                }
                           }
                                           
                setTimeout(grebData,time);
            }
        }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.stdin.resume();
    }
};


setTimeout(grebData,time);

app.listen(3001,'0.0.0.0');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout` with the desired time at the end of `grebData`. You would then also need to replace each existing `setInterval` with `setTimeout`.

([setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/setInterval) is periodic, [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) fires only once.)

I'm not sure about your plans and intentions. But changing the waiting time on the fly would work like this:

```
var time = 15000;
function grebData(time) {

    try {

        // Your loops, possibly changing the time value

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.stdin.resume();
    }
    setTimeout(grepData,time);
}
setTimeout(grebData,time);
```

I think you need to realize that when `grepData` returns, it will not reach the code below it. It's asynchronous.

Comment: In this case I would still need to set another variable to call the setTimeout n1 or the setTimeout n2 right?

Comment: The problem is that I need the script breaking and waiting x1 and x2 times along the looping.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Let me adjust your code.

Comment: Needs to be inside the try/catch. Worked fine. Thank you